# Use semi-direct product to construct non-abelian group from abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be abelian. $\exists h\in H$ s.t. $h^2\neq e$. I want to use semi-direct products to construct a non-abelian group $G$ s.t. $G$ has subgroup $K$ with index $2$ that is isomorphic to $H$.

Let $N \subset Aut(H)$ with homomorphism $\phi:N \rightarrow Aut(H)$. Now define $G=N \rtimes_\phi H = \{(n,h):n\in N, h \in H\}$. Then $(n_1,h_1)(n_2,h_2)=n_1h_1n_2h_2=(n_1\phi_{h_1}n_2, h_1h_2)\neq (h_1h_2,n_1\phi_{h_1}n_2)$. Have I shown that $G$ is non-abelian? How about the index 2 subgroup?

Comment: Is there any certain abelian group and that $N$ in your mind?

Comment: The normal subgroup?

Comment: I really don't get the last $\neq$ part, I mean, if $h \in H$ and $n \in N$, writing $(h,n)$ is not even well-defined in $N \rtimes_{\phi} H$.

Comment: The generalized dihedral group, $Dih(H)$, is the group $G$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_dihedral_group

Comment: And then $K=\{(h,0):h\in H\}\subset Dih(H)$ has index 2. Well done.